# UITableView Sectionheaders each with a button, but just the first Button sends action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i add a button to my Sectionheaders, but only the first Button works.
The other Buttons neither show a animation on touch nor send a action.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
//Headerview
UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
//HeaderLabel
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 5.0, 300.0, 30.0)] ;
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.286 green:0.341 blue:0.424 alpha:1.];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//AddParameterButton
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(275.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
button.tag = section;
button.hidden = NO;
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(insertParameter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

label.text = @"Parameter";
[myView addSubview:label];
[myView addSubview:button];
[myView bringSubviewToFront:button];
[label release];
return myView;
}
```

Any solving proposals?
THANK YOU
**//edit:**
i debugged a bit and the `viewForHeaderInSection:` gets called six times but there are only two sections. hope i can help
**//edit2**
tried to add the buttons as property and do it the nondynamic way, but doesn't help, too

Comment: I see only one button in this code. where are the others?

Comment: Or is it that you have one button each for every section and u are not able to get actions for buttons in other sections?

Comment: hi i got one button in every section and only the button in the first sectionheader sends a action

Comment: If you post your own answer then it is very fine but atleast you should show some generosity towards the answers which though were not completely correct but near to what you wanted. You should atleast upvote such answers. You can refer to this : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had in my heightForHeaderInsection

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (section < 2)
    return 40;
return 10;
}
```

changed it and work fine
so thank you very much, think i'm a little codeblind
sorry and thank you

Comment: Atleast accept your answer so that others get to know that it is already answered.

Answer (score 2):

@Seega:

Try to set unique identifiers for each of the buttons buttons.

Basically I am talking about button tags and then try to access the buttons by its tag in the `insertParameter:` method, I think this would solve your problem.

As you have one button per section, what I feel is that you have best option to set tag as `indexPath.section`

You can add the tag in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method as shown below

```
[button setTag:section];
```

OR

```
button.tag = section;
```

So try using the button tags just to uniquely identify the button over each section.

Hope this helps you

Comment: i do this already `button.tag = section;`    
but if put a breakpoint in `insertParameter:` and push the second button the function doen't get called

Comment: @Seega: Do you just click or `click and hold` the button? Also what I would suggest is that you should try `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` instead of `UIControlEventTouchDown` to try and see if it works in that case. Do try this and let me know what happens.

Comment: @Seega: oops..I didnt see that you have got your answer.Meanwhile I was trying to figure out bug in your code and it tried it on my Mac and it worked well for me. Anyways thats fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should create buttons for each section. Use an if condition and and put your code inside each block.

```
if (section == 0) 
{

//code to create your button

}
else if(section == 1) 
{

//code to create your button

}

else
{

//code to create your button

}
```

Try this.